# How to foce Paypal page language locale in paypal API

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am using website standards and using the PayPal api using subscriptions and want to force the page into Spanish, for example. My attempt was to use the LC post variable, below, but it doesnt do anything.

```
$p->add_field('lc','es');
```

How can I force the page into the language of my choosing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine, example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcuu8/).. Maybe post the output?

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="ES" />
```